# Mapping numbers

Tags: python

I know this is a noobish question put i could not figure it out >.<
I have an number from `-1000 to 1000` and I need to map it to numbers `0 to 200`.
I think it has to do with the `map()` function but i'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just assume that there's a native mapping of those 2 sets of numbers? How the hell does -1000 to 1000 map from 0 to 200

Comment: Im not sure if i worded it right. In this case 0 would be 100, -500, would be 50 and 500 would be 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"0 would be 100, -500, would be 50 and 500 would be 150"

Then try the following function:

```
def mapNumber(a):
    return int(a + 1000) / 10
```

This way:

```
mapNumber(-1000)
> 0

mapNumber(-500)
> 50

mapNumber(0)
> 100

mapNumber(500)
> 150

mapNumber(1000)
> 200
```

This will map your integers into integers. And since your target range is 10 times smaller, it will map ten different numbers to the same.

If you want to get a floating point number, try this:

```
def mapNumber(a):
    return (a + 1000.) / 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input range [-1000,1000] is much larger than the output range of [0,200], many numbers will end up mapping to the same value in [0,200]. The simplest way to do this would be to take the modulo of the input number mod 201. This will always give you a number in [0,200].

If you need to do this to a `list` of numbers, you can use the `map` function like so

```
inlist=[-1000,9,999]
outlist=map(lambda x:x%201, inlist)
print outlist
```

It is often preferred in Python to use a list comprehension instead.

```
inlist=[-1000,9,999]
outlist=[x%201 for x in inlist]
print outlist
```

Comment: Mak, I don't understand the 'inlist=[-1000,9,999]'. Why not 'inlist = range(-1000, 1001)'?

Comment: @Uphill_What'1: I just used a small set of numbers as an example. You can use `range(-1000,1001)` to find out the mapping for all of them. But there is little use in precomputing them and looking then up from a `list` since it is just one operation and you can simply use the % operator to convert numbers on the fly as needed.